# get_post_meta() retrieves meta from a specific post on pages, not the page currently viewed

Tags: custom-field, pages

I am making a simple sidebar functionality to display embed video in the sidebar. I've created a meta field where admin should paste the embed video. It works as it should on posts, but on pages, `get_the_ID()` is always returning the same ID, 145, ID of one of the posts.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php 
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $video_value = get_post_meta($id, '_post_video', true);
    if (! empty($video_value)) {
        echo $video_value;
        echo get_the_ID();
    } else {
        echo 'no video to show';
        echo get_the_ID();
    }
?>
```

I am a bit confused, so if anyone could shad some light on this... Thanks!

Comment: @G.M. but this is outside of the loop, and there is no custom loop on either posts or pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some other query which replaces the main post ID. Might be another widget, some strange plugin code or something else If you have no control over the context, collect the post ID earlier:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'collect_post_id' );

function collect_post_id()
{
    static $id = 0;

    if ( 'template_redirect' === current_filter() && is_singular() )
        $id = get_the_ID();

    return $id;
}
```

Instead of `get_the_ID()` use `collect_post_id()` now in your code.

```
$video_value = get_post_meta( collect_post_id(), '_post_video', true );
```

Comment: why not to reset the query?

Comment: @MarkKaplun Which one? If you don’t know the context, you might break something.

Comment: ok, will just add it as an answer

Comment: thatnks, this worked, but I am curious why i had the problem in the first place, as I am just starting with this theme, so there is no other code or plugin that could affect it, and what is the difference between posts and pages in this case, as on posts it worked as it should?

Comment: What exactly changes the main query depends on the actual code. I don’t know that, so I have no idea. :) Maybe a shortcode?

Answer (score 1):

[`get_the_ID`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) is intented to be used **within** The Loop.

From Codex:

> This tag must be within The Loop.

Use:

```
$id = get_queried_object_ID();
```

See [here](http://queryposts.com/function/get_queried_object_id/) for docs.

Comment: The docs are lying. That function requires just a global post object, which is available when `is_singular()` is `TRUE`, eg. on pages or single posts.

Comment: I'm not completely sure about that... [`get_the_ID()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_id/) calls [`get_post()->ID`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_post/), which (for an empty/`null` `$post`) argument, then calls `WP_Post::get_instance()`.

Comment: I know. In the comment OP says there's no custom loop on pages, so I guessed something, probably another widget, is breaking global `$post`, but - normally - the queried object should be not fucked up, unless the widget is using `query_posts` in that case that widget should be disabled :) @toscho

Answer (score 0):

somewhere in your site's code there is a costume query loop that doesn't reset the main loop parameters after it is finished. The right thing to do is to hunt it down and call `wp_reset_query()` when it finishes, the alternative is to call it in the beginning of your code

```
wp_reset_query()
$id = get_the_ID();
$video_value = get_post_meta($id, '_post_video', true);
...
```

Comment: You can insert widget areas between items in a custom loop. Calling `wp_reset_query()` without knowing that would trigger some really ugly side effects.

Comment: yes, but that is a very edge case, most similar problems that I witnessed were solved by using wp_reset_query.